# c# program to corrupt a file

Tags: c#, .net

I want a program to corrupt a file. When my app access directoryinfo.getfiles(), it receives an exception saying the file is corrupted or unreadable.

I want a program to corrupt a file in the file system so that i can simulate the exception .

Any ideas /help would be appreciated.

Raju

Comment: Please specify what constitutes a *valid* file first. Without that information, we cannot determine how to *actually* corrupt your files.

Comment: Is the exception the OS's exception or is it some framework's?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem more than a software one.

Comment: The file is a log file where in app writes some events to the log file. I think this is the OS exception. There are no rules for the valif file. The onlyway to shutdown the app was to shutoff the power. So while power shutdown, the file got corrupted

Comment: Do you also plan on erasing your hard disk to simulate the exception thrown when Windows fails to read from a drive? I don't really recommend this... There are better ways of testing exception handlers than wrecking your disks to do it.

Comment: @user209293, if there are no rules for file validity, then all files are always valid. Subsequently, no file can ever be invalid, so your question cannot be answered.

Comment: @Cody What would those ways be?

Comment: @Shane: That sounds like a whole new question to me... Or what this question should have been... (Feel free to edit it and make it *into* that. That would be a way better question. In fact, that was the point I was trying to make with that comment, that he should be asking about those ways instead.)

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the corrupted file that's already caused the exception. You could embed it as a resource or something then write it out if you really want.

Out of curiosity, why do you want a program that corrupts a file for testing against a particular exception, when an already corrupted file that causes said exception won't do?

Comment: This happend at the customer location. I don't have the corrupted file.

Comment: In that case @Shane's answer is as good as any. You can probably just write random bytes at the start, which might be easier than writing to random locations.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in Binary, then write random bytes in random places to it.

Comment: The above suggestions corrupts the file. But it doesn't corrupt the file related data in the file system. I am getting an exception while calling DirectoryInfo.getFiles. I think when there is a corruption of file in the fise system then only i can get the exception while calling directoryinfo.getfiles.

Comment: @user209293 Well then I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you override the first or last bytes of a file it will probably gets corrupted since most of file formats use there for `format information` (ZIP and RAR use end of file so streaming would be supported).